# jQuery slider fails to load on first page load?

Tags: jquery

The slider on my home page has a mind of it's own and rarely loads correctly when i first go to the website. http://www.dailyshowbusiness.com

The slider should have 1 large image with the 3 smaller (choices) images below, usually when i type the domain and press enter all i can see is the 3 smaller images, but not the main image.

Now if i click on another page and then click on home the plugin loads correctly.

Why is it not loading the first time. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this file `http://www.dailyshowbusiness.com/addons/shared_addons/themes/dailyshowbiz/js/scripts.js`
Line 1
Try to set a fixed height for the slider (500px) or call that function on `window.load`.

The problem is: when the images were not loaded yet, the plugin set `height = 0px` so you can not see it at all.

Comment: Thanks for that, i'm not sure how to set the height within the plugin? so i tried your $(window).load(function() {} method which seems to work but now there is a noticeable delay when the plugin loads, it's only brief but if you reset the page you can see the list style bullets, they soon disappear but it's not ideal.

Comment: add in your `css` this: `ul#carousel{list-style: none}` to remove the bullets. This is just a minor fix because the plugin itself has problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in  document ready  function

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$('#carousel').infiniteCarousel({
    transitionSpeed: 800,
    displayTime: 10000,
    displayProgressRing: false,
    progressRingColorOpacity: '0,0,0,.5',
    progressRingBackgroundOn: false,
    thumbnailType: 'images',
    easeLeft: 'linear',
    easeRight:'linear',
    imagePath: './addons/shared_addons/themes/dailyshowbiz/img/',
    inView: 1,
    margin: 0,
    advance: 1,
    customClass: 'myCarousel',
    showControls: false,
    autoHideCaptions: false,
    autoPilot: true,
    prevNextInternal: true,
    internalThumbnails: false,
    enableKeyboardNav: false
});

});
```

Comment: I've tried it within $(document).ready(function(){} but it still fails to fire up from time to time, the (window).load method above seems to work better but there is a much bigger delay. you can see the list styling when it first loads which disappears after 1 second.